# How to place a checkpoint in DocuSign Document

Tags: node.js, docusignapi

Say I have two documents in an envelope, after clicking this [start button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oYoDS.png), I want to navigate to the start of the next document or navigate to x page of x document? Is there any way to do that programatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To navigate to a certain page that I wanted, I created a required and read-only text field (tab) during makeEnvelope process like so:

```
let textHere1 = docusign.Text.constructFromObject({
   documentId: "4",
   pageNumber: "1",
   tabLabel: "#bookmark1",
   value: " ",
   yPosition: "380",
});
```

Comment: You can also use the tabOrder property to make sure this happens in the right sequence for your signers (now that I realized you can just jump somewhere, when does the jump happens?)

Answer (score 0):

The DocuSign Signing UI will help the signer navigate the document by taking them to the next signing element (also called tab/tag) based on the logic that was designed in the envelope. That's the behavior you see after clicking "Start."

There's no way that I know of to just place a tab that does nothing except take the user to that position in the document. Typically the tab requires the user to click to have their signature or initial or fill a text box or checkbox etc. and that Start button text changes to tell the user what to do in that field.

Comment: I created a textfield to make the checkpoint that I wanted. So basically it's a required and read-only textfield.